# Java empty output file

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io, file-writing, storing-data

I'm trying to get the program to read from an input file, sort the data into an ArrayList and then save to a different file.
The program runs fine and shows the results, but the output file comes up empty.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String text1 = "";
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("input.txt"))){
            try (Formatter output = new Formatter("output.txt")){

            List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                text1 = input.next();
                text.add(text1);
            }
            input.close();

            String[] textArray = text.toArray(new String[0]);
            for (String s: textArray) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            }
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you appending to `output`?

Comment: You're not writing to the output file.

Comment: `System.out.println(s);` you are writing to console instead of output file.

Comment: add `output.format("%s", s)` in your loop to at least use the `Formatter`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: FYI : you can iterate the list instead of the array ? And if you use `toArray`, provide the correct length directly with `new String[text.size()]`

Answer (score 2):

One problem was using `.next()` instead of `.nextLine()`

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("input.txt"))){
    try (Formatter output = new Formatter("output.txt")){
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String text1 = input.nextLine();
            output.format("%s\r\n", text1);
        }
    }
}
```

But better use [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

```
Path inputPath = Paths.get("input.txt");
Path outputPath = Paths.get("output.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(inputPath);
lines.sort();
Files.write(outputPath, lines);
```

Comment: The other problem was to not use the `Formatter` ;) PS : Why do you use Windows line separator ? You can use `%n` if you want a separator dependent of the OS in `format` method.

Comment: @AxelH Today I already used `%n` but creating a text file on a linux server for a Windows client makes an extra `\r` safer, as Notepad still is stubborn. Formatter _is_ usable, though I never used it in my life (as many). But I did give a better alternative. Nevertheless a valuable comment. I would even add that besides Formatter, Scanner too is a bit of a two headed monster, doing tokens.

Comment: Well, you said it all ! I can't agree more.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually write to the file, you only print each line in your `println` statement

Try adding something like:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(s);
```

Comment: No bother. This was just an example - there are many ways to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing to the file as it been opened as Writing as well as reading mode.I have made changes to your code hope it will help you

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String text1 = "";
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("input.txt"))){
            try (Formatter output = new Formatter("output.txt")){

            List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                text1 = input.next();
                text.add(text1);
            }
           input.close();

            String[] textArray = text.toArray(new String[0]);
            for (String s: textArray) {
                output.format("%s",s);
                System.out.println(s);
            }
                 output.close();
            }
      }
}
```